# URL submit with "get" mode, response"400" error

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, web

when I raise request with follow url:

```
myip/searchapp/genericSearch/genericSearchInit.html?securityName=&identifierType=3&identifierCode=test&vendor=4&startDate=10%252F1%252F2013&priceType=&currency=&endDate=&exchange=
```

I got 400 error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

But when I give some values such as

```
myip/searchapp/genericSearch/genericSearchInit.html?securityName=&identifierType=3&identifierCode=test&vendor=4&startDate=10%252F1%252F2013&priceType=1&currency=1&endDate=1&exchange=1
```

and it become legal url.

can any guy tell me why? and how can I deal with it?

Comment: Is this your service? It may be that server web service method crashes due to null pointer on exchange parameter - So it's just bad request.

Comment: So the only difference is when the query string contains `exchange=` instead of `exchange=1` it fails? We have no idea what your app does or why it should do anything with specific input.  If you want some help you need to show the code.

Comment: @JimGarrison I do not think it is necessary to show the code, I think it is problem about legal url. but I can find out:/

Comment: @MGorgon not only the exchange, but all behind four parameter given values, it work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving out those last parts completely if you don't need them:

```
myip/searchapp/genericSearch/genericSearchInit.html?securityName=&identifierType=3&identifierCode=test&vendor=4&startDate=10%252F1%252F2013
```

it must be that whatever page you are calling is using those variables to redirect to different pages. It seems that the page breaks when an empty string is sent in.

That page is probably using key_exists() checks, which would return false if the query didn't have it at all but true if you sent an empty string, and not an additional empty() checks, which would return false either way.

If that page is yours, then you could probably adjust it so that the it is valid to send empty data. If it isn't yours then it is just the way that specific page is working, there really isn't anything else to understand.

It is a bug, report it to whoever is in charge of the page.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is a solution, but I want to know why it doesn't work, you see the securityName parameter is null, but it can work well.

Comment: I have some idea about this issue, I will check first and confirm my conclusion.

Comment: ****hello guy, I found the key point. I use the spring MVC, and it will assembly the form bean automatically, but the exchange and some other fields is Integer type, when give null value to them, there will be an 400 error happens, I changed these field to String, and it work fine now!:) thank you for your reply, if any body have same issue, refer to my comments!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I can tell in those two urls is

```
priceType=&currency=&endDate=&exchange=
```

versus

```
priceType=1&currency=1&endDate=1&exchange=1
```

It seems the server doesn't like missing data and therefore sends 400 Bad Request. You need to figure out what your service expects and send that.